# Suppress space between Chinese and Roman typeface in XeLaTeX

Tags: spacing, xetex, cjk

When the Roman characters [a-z0-9] and Chinese characters alternate in XeLaTeX, a space is automatically entered between the two types of character. For example, both `Abcde我fg` and `Abcde 我 fg` produce:

[image: spaces entered]

Ordinarily, it is stylistically correct to include these spaces, but my question is whether there is a straightforward way to suppress them if I choose to for certain reasons.

(I am using the packages `xeCJK` and `fontspec`.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `\CJKsetecglue` command sets the separation character between Chinese and English blocks of text, the default being `\CJKsetecglue{ }`. So a simple `\CJKsetecglue{}` should do the trick.

Comment: It certainly does. Short and sweet — the kind of TeX solution I like best. Thanks!