# Temporarily changing the spacing between Chinese text and numerals

Tags: spacing, xetex, cjk, xecjk

When mixing Chinese text and non-math mode numbers together within a sentence, narrow numbers are given the same amount of space as characters:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ctexcap}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{Adobe Heiti Std}
\begin{document}
    第1号
\end{document}
```

In most situations, this appearance is probably ideal, however, in my case, I need to temporarily change this spacing, in a small number of instances. How can I force the characters to be printed closer to the "1" one has the same spacing it would have if it were placed among English text (with no spaces on either side)?

Comment: also [Suppress space between Chinese and Roman typeface in XeLaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16034/suppress-space-between-chinese-and-roman-typeface-in-xelatex)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `\CJKsetecglue` to set the spaces between CJK symbols and western symbols. This is documented in `xeCJK`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ctexcap} % it will load xeCJK internally. Or just use ctexart instead of article
\setCJKmainfont{Adobe Heiti Std}
\CJKsetecglue{\hskip0.15em plus0.05em minus 0.05em}
\begin{document}
  第1号
\end{document}
```

However, you must be careful when you use a `\hskip` other than normal inter-word space. `\CJKsetecglue` only sets the space between the two different character class in XeTeX. There are still many cases `xeCJK` cannot add sapces automatically.

For example,

```
汉字\mbox{abc}汉字 % no spaces added
```

You should add proper spacing (but not a space) yourself these cases.

Comment: I don't want to change the spacing for the entire document, just in specific places. Is there a way to do this without changing all of the spacing everywhere?

Comment: @Village: Just use `\CJKsetecglue{...}` in the group or envrionment you want. This is basic LaTeX usage like setting `\rmfamily` or redefining `\arraystretch`.