# Extra spaces when using fancyvrb with xeCJK

Tags: fancyvrb, xecjk

I am trying to typeset text including CJK ideographs in a `verbatim` environment.  Because I want to indent my `verbatim` text slightly, I am using the [`fancyvrb`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb?lang=en) package.  Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parskip}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{verbatim}{Verbatim}{xleftmargin=2em}

\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmonofont{Noto Sans CJK JP}

\begin{document}
Code like this\ldots
\begin{verbatim}
auto x = "林";
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

However I find there's an extra space character in the output, immediately between the opening double-quote and the ideograph.

[image: Screeshot]

It does seem to be a space character and not just excessive kerning, as it copies-and-pastes from the PDF as a space character.  Can anyone see how to get rid of it?  In case it's relevant, I'm using XeLaTeX version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99996.

It doesn't happen with LaTeX's built-in `verbatim` environment, but I don't know a way of altering the margins of that.  I'm not wedded to using `fancyvrb`, if I can set the left margin of the `verbatim` environment some other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm having the same problem as you. It's because xeCJK is inserting glue (a whitespace by default) between english and CJK characters.

**Solution 1:**

```latex
\xeCJKsetup{xCJKecglue={}}
```

Be careful that this is a global setup, it will affect the whole document, not only the verbatim environment.

**Solution 2:**

Wrap verbatim env inside `{\CJKsetecglue{} ...your normal code... }`, so it only takes effect locally.

```latex
{
    \CJKsetecglue{}
    \begin{verbatim}
    auto x = "林";
    \end{verbatim}
}
```

Comment: In the end I went with a compromise between your two solutions, and used a `\renewenvironment{verbatim}` to do the `\CJKsetecglue{}` automatically along the lines of [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1266/is-it-possible-to-define-a-verbatim-command/1277#1277).  I didn't want to do it unconditionally (per your first solution) because that glue is needed in ordinary text (e.g. "Set x to contain the glyph 林").

Comment: Also, now I know what to search for, [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16034) is essentially the same problem.

Comment: I too know what to search for after reading xeCJK document. Other than `\renewenvironment` you can also use `\AtBeginEnvironment{verbatim}{\CJKsetecglue{}}`